# Does OPA accepts XML as data /input?

Tags: xml

Can OPA supports XML document as input ?
I got an use case to parse the xml data and do further data manipulation using OPA policy .

tried with json but xml support is required

Answer (score 0):

No, OPA does not support XML as input. You'll need to make the conversion from XML to JSON in the client before sending it off to OPA for a policy decision.